# Conversion of 64 bit integer back to two 32 bit integers

Tags: python, numpy, math, 32bit-64bit, bit

I need help reversing this conversion logic:

```
word0 = np.uint32(3333333333)
word1 = np.uint32(1111111111)

temp64 = np.uint64(word0) * 1000000000
temp64 = temp64 + np.uint64(word1)
```

`temp64` now holds the value of a timestamp. I need to convert this back to two 32 bit ints and arrive at `word0 = 3333333333` and `word1 = 1111111111`

```
word0 = np.uint32(3333333333) # 32bit
word1 = np.uint32(1111111111) # 32bit

temp64 = np.uint64(word0) * 1000000000
temp64 = np.uint64(temp64) + np.uint64(word1)

temp32_0 = np.uint64((temp64)/1000000000)
temp32_1 = np.uint64(temp64%1000000000)

print(temp32_0)
print(temp32_1)
```

---

OUTPUT:

```
3333333334
111111168
```

I need to get back to

```
3333333333
1111111111
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `4294967296` instead of `1000000000`, which make the two values overlap, and thus be inseperable.

Whatever factor is chosen, it must be larger than `3333333333`, not less.

Look what happens with the smaller values `33` and `11` using the factor `10`.

```
33 * 10 + 11 = 341
```

And then extracting:

```
341 / 10 = 34
341 % 10 = 1
```

Comment: I don't have a say in changing that value. This is existing logic being used to encode some data.

Comment: Well my example shows why you are getting wrong values. Should there be one more `0` after `1000000000`, that is, `10000000000`? Or, should that be a `hex` value factor: `0x1000000000`? As it stands, you *can't* reverse the logic, because the two values have merged. My example shows that the pairs `33`,`11` and `34`,`1` both produce the same value `341`.

Comment: ... as do `31`,`31` and `32`,`21`. There is not a unique solution to the recovery of the original values.

Comment: Your scheme will work only for numbers up to `999999999`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, look at line `temp64 = np.uint64(word0) * 1000000000`.
if you check type of `temp64`, it would be numpy.float64! So, you need to convert 1000000000 to uint64 first.

Without numpy it looks better:

```
# overlapping case
word0 = 3333333333
word1 = 1111111111
factor = 1000000000
temp64 = word0 * factor
temp64 = temp64 + word1

print(divmod(temp64, factor))

# non-overlapping case
word0 = 3333333333
word1 = 1111111111
factor = 10000000000  #extra zero added
temp64 = word0 * factor
temp64 = temp64 + word1

print(divmod(temp64, factor))
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider also bit shifts and another bitwise operations:

```
word0 = 3333333333
word1 = 1111111111
temp64 = (word0 << 32) | word1
print(temp64)
word00 = temp64 >> 32
word11 = temp64 & 0xFFFFFFFF
print(word00, word11)

>>14316557653012788679
>>3333333333 1111111111
```